# How to login to JavaScript form and scrape using python

Tags: javascript, python, forms, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to login to this page to scrape information from it , but I could not pass the form , it's not like any other I have logged into using **BeautifulSoup** , **Requests** and **urllib**  in python 3.8 .

I have no idea what to post or where to put the payload or literally anything at this point knowing I have 0 experience in Java Script.

http://mygate.aiu.edu.sy:8080/faces/ui/pages/student/index.xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two ways - hard way and easy way.

- The hard way - you need to monitor all the requests page sends when you logging in in the real browser (through "Network" tab in Chrome or FF dev tools), and then you need to replicate them on your side to look like a real user. You can do it with `requests`+`BeautifulSoup`, but I'll better use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) because it has built-in support for saving cookies between requests, etc.
- The easy way, and it's still Python - use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). This way you're operating through the real browser, you can just send `click on that thing` commands, and browser will do all the work, including "looking like a real browser", so you'll skip a lot of antibot stuff.